# ASP.NET MVC RedirectToAction changes -v4.5 & v4.7.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Has there been any major changes between v4.5 and v4.7.2 in the way RedirectToAction is treated in ASP.NET MVC. I used to have a method like this

```
TakeMeSomeWhere(string a, string b, string c = "")
```

And, from another action method, I used to call this

```
var routeValues = new { a = "somevalue", b = "somevalue", c = "somevalue" }
RedirectToAction(TakeMeSomeWhere, routeValues)
```

This used to work until I upgraded my project to 4.7.2 from 4.5. After that I could see the HttpResponse with 302 (which is expected), but the redirect url has been completely different and the url has 2 query string parameters as "`?Type=Object&Value=<serialized string of the object, routeValues>`". Before that the url was formed as "`?a=somevalue&b-somevalue&c=somevalue`" and the routing used to happen without any problem.

Adding proper code

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult IntermediateAction(string source, string jOject)
{
    dynamic paramObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jOject);
    var routeParameter = new
    {
        pageSource = paramObject.PageSource,
        caller = paramObject.Url,
        details = paramObject.Details,
        id = paramObject.Id
    };
    
    // a switch case is here on "source"
    return this.RedirectToAction("TakeMeSomeWhere", routeParameter);
}

public ActionResult TakeMeSomeWhere(string pageSource, string caller, string details = null, string id = null)
```

Comment: This seems incorrect to me: `RedirectToAction(TakeMeSomeWhere, routeValues)`. Shouldn't `TakeMeSomeWhere` be surrounded with quotes? The first parameter of `RedirectToAction` must be a string.

Comment: @Rudey That's just pseudo code. I hope you get the gist of the issue.

Comment: `RedirectToAction` works fine in my 4.7.2 project, so the devil must be in the details. Any chance you can share some snippets of the code that's actually running into the issue you're describing?

Comment: @Rudey, the code is added in the original post.

Comment: `// a switch case is here on "source"` What does this mean? Please share a [mcve].

Comment: @mjwills, what I meant was, according to the "source" parameter, the destination action method changes. So we have a switch case there which determines the action method to go to. That is irrelevant here so didn't copy it.

Comment: `That is irrelevant here` Maybe it is relevant?

Comment: @mjwills, it is not. the switch statement determines the action name, according to the source it goes to different action methods with the same set of parameters.